# Tool tip in d3 is not working inside rect of zoomable graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am facing an Issue by enabling the tool tip of the Zoomable line graph with Scatter plot(added by me) in the line graph.
The tool-tip doesn't works in the graph,When i hover on the circle and it works when i remove the `.rect` part of the code. 
My Sample line graph code which i had taken is this [Sample Line Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f) Atleast 80% of the code matches with this sample code.

I have found this thread but there are no accurate answers on this,so placing a question.
[D3: How to handle zooming and tooltips in a single chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150969/d3-how-to-handle-zooming-and-tooltips-in-a-single-chart)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Functionally, you can probably make this work by drawing the rect "underneath" the bottom chart (this means moving the "svg.append("rect")" part of the code up).

However, this seems like a bad user experience in general (since dragging the rectangle will likely cause tooltips to be displayed, which seems annoying)

Comment: Thanks @maggiomj it worked and dragging the rectangle is not displaying the tooltip but it kind of pauses the scatterport when i drag the rectangle...any fix for this ?